# Bootstrap with navbar fixed top and Bootstro

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstro

I am using Bootstrap + Bootstro but can't make the top navbar to get behind the overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/NJsYw/5/ (click on Tutorial)

```
<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#" id='tutorial'>Tutorial</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    </div>
    <p class="lead bootstro" data-bootstro-title='Title' data-bootstro-content="Description." data-bootstro-width="400px" data-bootstro-placement='bottom' data-bootstro-step='0'>Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>
    <p class="bootstro" data-bootstro-title='Title' data-bootstro-content="Description." data-bootstro-width="400px" data-bootstro-placement='bottom' data-bootstro-step='1'>Back to <a href="./sticky-footer.html">the sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="push"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Looks like this was address here https://github.com/clu3/bootstro.js/issues/15 but I didn't know how to apply (if it is necessary)

Thanks

Comment: Your looking to have the header `fixed` as you scroll down?

Comment: Please define the problem in details, thank you for providing the fiddle. I can see the fiddle but not able to understand problem. also there are some settings which are over written, using the included CSS file so we should modify / remove it.

Comment: The problem is the top nav bar wasn't get overhide by bootstro when I click in Tutorial (if the option isn't showing up, maximaze the output area. I want the whole page to be semi transparent black... and the top nav isn't I want it to be too

Comment: Oh I see now.  `click on Tutorial` the use of `in` was confusing me. I was thinking you were referring to opening your fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using `CSS` the key is `z-index` which specifies the stack order of an element.

The bootstrap `navbar` has a `z-index` of 1030 so in order for the `bootstro backdrop` to cover the navbar you need to adjust the `z-index` to be higher than 1030.
e.g.

```
.bootstro-backdrop
{
    ....
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

You also need to make sure that the bootstrap `popover` is not covered so you need to increase its z-index to be higher than `2000`.

```
.popover {
    z-index:2001;   
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NJsYw/8/)

Comment: Thanks Trevor, it works. But I found another situation with a specific button and bootstro... will post here soon, but you already have my reputation.